# Functions in math.h don't return the expected value

Tags: c

The program I'm making is supposed to calculate the following function:

```
f(x,y)= 2 sin(x) + cos(y) - tg(x+y)
```

I tried to do the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double toDegrees(double radians){
  return radians * (180.0 / M_PI);
}

int main(void){
  double x,y;
  printf("What's the value of x?\n");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  printf("What's the value of y?\n");
  scanf("%lf", &y);
  printf("The values are %lf\n", toDegrees(2*sin(x)+cos(y)-tan(x+y)));
  return 0;
}
```

The function toDegrees will convert the default output of the functions from math.h from radians to degrees.

The expected output in radians without the function toDegrees is `-2.07746705002370603998583034482545686045261881310920233482`

That is indeed the output.

The expected output in degrees with the function toDegrees is `1.881737400858622861572140743032864796565271853728846372576`

The output, however, is `-119.030094`.

The output I'm expecting is the output I got with `x=10` and `y=21` in [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*sin%2810%29%2Bcos%2821%29%2Btan%2810%2B21%29&assumption=%22TrigRD%22%20-%3E%20%22D%22).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I did put -lm is the compilation.

Comment: Side note: at the top you write `- tg(x+y)`, but in your code you have `+tan(x+y)`.

Comment: Oh, nice catch! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a programming error but a math error: it's the inputs to the trig functions that are angles in degrees or radians, not the outputs. Also, your conversion is the wrong way around: you want to convert degrees to radians, not radians to degrees.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double toRadians(double degrees){
  return degrees * (M_PI / 180.0);
}

int main(void){
  double x,y;
  printf("What's the value of x?\n");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  printf("What's the value of y?\n");
  scanf("%lf", &y);
  printf("The values are %lf\n", 2*sin(toRadians(x))+cos(toRadians(y))+tan(toRadians(x+y)));
  return 0;
}
```

With both of those errors fixed, entering `10` for x and `21` for y correctly returns the `1.881737` that you want.

Comment: Isn't their default output in radians? That's why I converted them to degrees

Comment: Their default INPUT is radians, so you need to convert your values, which are degrees, TO radians, and then pass them to the functions. The OUTPUT is neither degrees nor radians, as it no longer represents an angle, but rather a ratio.

Comment: Ah, right, I get it; was making a confusion, thank you!